# Confusion on integration by parts on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: integration, measure-theory, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

For two vector fields $X$ and $Y$ on a Riemannian manifold $M$ with metric $g$, we define
$$\langle X, Y \rangle_{L^2} = \int_M g_{ij}X^iY^j dV.$$
I have been unable to find a similar expression for two functions $f,g \in C_0(M)$. I am guessing that this will just be
$$\langle f, g \rangle = \int_M fgdV \tag{1}$$
Why do we not have to take the complex conjugate as in Euclidean space?

But if this definition is correct, consider the heat equation:
$$\partial_t u - \Delta u = 0$$
so that $u: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. In [these](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/%7Egrigor/cuhk19.pdf) set of notes they state
$$\langle \Delta u, u\rangle_{L^2} = \int_M (\Delta u)u d\mu = -\int_M |\nabla u|^2 d\mu \leq 0 \tag{2}$$
where they take $d\mu$ to be the Riemannian measure.

Using (1), (2) is obtained from integrating by parts as one usually does on Euclidean space with $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure. Does this just mean we can always treat $dV$ (or $d\mu$ in the notation of the notes) to be some multiple of the Lebesgue measure? If so, what justifies this? If not, what justifies the integration by parts formula as in (2)?

Lastly, I have seen the integration by parts formula on a Riemannian manifold (for example, [here](https://arbourj.wordpress.com/2013/12/19/integration-by-parts-and-greens-formula-on-riemannian-manifolds/)) given as
$$\int_M \langle \nabla f, X \rangle = -\int_M f div X + \int_{\partial M} f \langle X, \nu \rangle.$$
But what is the relationship between this formula and the integration by parts of scalar functions as in (2)?

Comment: It is instructive to do these in coordinates. Particularly the last formula, which is not so easy since the integration by parts picks up a boundary term. But by a good choice of coordinates, you obtain $\int_{\partial M}f\langle X, \nu \rangle \,dS$ as the boundary term. The proofs here are good: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Proofs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why do we not have to take the complex conjugate as in Euclidean space?

Because we’re dealing with real-valued stuff.

> “Does this just mean we can always treat $dV$ (or $d\mu$ in the notation of the notes) to be some multiple of the Lebesgue measure?”

This makes no sense. There is no “Lebesgue measure” on $M$ in the sense of a non-zero translation-invariant measure (translations don’t even make sense in general). All we have is the Riemannian measure (we can call it the Riemann-Lebesgue measure if we wish, since its a measure arising in Riemannian geometry, and it’s defined on a $\sigma$-algebra on $M$ which is analogous to the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra on open sets of some $\Bbb{R}^n$, and in any chart domain, this measure pushes forward to a measure on an open subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$ which is absolutely continuous relative to the usual Lebesgue measure).

> If not, what justifies the integration by parts formula as in (2)?

I think you’re forgetting the obvious fact that Laplacians $\Delta u$ are **by definition** the divergence of the gradient vector field. So, (2) really is a special case of the final quoted formula (please don’t memorize that… just derive it on the spot so you always know why it’s true). Integration by parts in 1D is really just a matter of doing a product rule in reverse, and applying the fundamental theorem of calculus. In higher dimensions, it is a matter of doing a variant of a product rule in reverse, and applying Stokes’ theorem or divergence theorem. For a slight generalization of your situation (also, writing $\nabla u$ to mean the vector field $\text{grad}_g(u)$):
\begin{align}
(\Delta u) v=(\text{div } \nabla u)v=\text{div}(v\,\nabla(u))-\langle\nabla v,\nabla u\rangle_g
\end{align}
Now, integrate both sides over $M$ using the measure $d\mu$.
Now suppose either $M$ is compact and boundaryless, or that $u$ or $v$ decays sufficiently rapidly or some other assumption which allows you to invoke the divergence theorem and discard the resulting boundary term. This gives
\begin{align}
\int_M(\Delta u)v\,d\mu&=0-\int_{M}\langle\nabla v,\nabla u\rangle_g\,d\mu.
\end{align}
If you now take $v=u$, then you get
\begin{align}
\int_M(\Delta u)u\,d\mu&=-\int_M\|\nabla u\|_g^2\,d\mu\leq 0.
\end{align}

Why did I redo the derivation? To emphasize that you shouldn’t be memorizing these things and that you should just do the integration-by-parts by-hand. Anyway, if you want to apply formulae, then take $f=u$ and $X=\nabla u$, and impose extra assumptions on $u$ or $M$ to discard the boundary term.

Comment: + over 9000 for `you shouldn’t be memorizing these things and that you should just do the integration-by-parts by-hand`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I would like to get to the point where I can derive everything on the spot but I've been having a hard time keeping all the geometric intuition in my head. If I may ask what I hope is not a trivial question, how can one prove the product rule for the divergence without resorting to coordinates?

Comment: @CBBAM What's your definition of divergence? Anywya, it all boils down to the fact that in whatever incarnation you look at it (local coordinate formula, or as the trace of the $(1,1)$ tensor field $\nabla X$, or using Lie derivatives or whatever else) it's a *first order derivative*. Derivatives will obey a product rule, since that's what they're designed to do.

Comment: @CBBAM In addition to the above explanation, it might help to notice that $\langle \nabla u, \nabla v\rangle = g^{ij} \nabla_iu \nabla_jv = \mathrm{trace}_g(\nabla u\otimes \nabla v)$.

Comment: besides, for geometric intuition, 90% of these formulas are direct word-for-word copies of formulas you'll see in an introductory electromagnetism/vector calculus book (such as Griffiths), and the proofs are identical too. The only thing you'll have to change is the meaning of the products (what E&M books will call the dot product, you simply have to mentally replace with "inner product relative to the metric tensor $g$"). Basic formulas like divergence theorem, Green's formulas (first and second), the various "integration-by-parts" tricks etc all look the same regardless of context.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you. I am comfortable deriving all this in a Euclidean setting, it is once I start working on a Riemannian manifold that I become less confident. I need to build an intuition on when/how/why the metric appears in these formulas for the Riemannian case.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I am most comfortable with the definition of the divergence given in Lee's book on smooth manifolds: $div X = *^{-1} d(\beta(X))$ where $*f = f dV$ and $\beta(X) = \iota_X dV$

Comment: like I said, as long as you only deal with first derivatives, formulas will look almost identical in the flat Euclidean case and the general Riemannian/Lorentzian case (because the same algebraic steps are used to prove the formulas in both cases). Second derivatives are a little trickier due to curvature terms which might pop up.

Comment: @Didier Thank you

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you, I will prove those formulas as an exercise to myself.

Comment: just ask yourself what happens in that definition of $X$ is replaced by $hX$ for a function $h$. Interior products are $C^{\infty}$ linear so the function $h$ jumps out of the interior product. Then you have to deal with the exterior derivative $d$, but those you know satisfy a product rule (no minus signs here since $h$ is a 0-form). Then just work out what the Hodge star does to it all. Though... I should say this isn't my favourite definition since it doesn't make it apparent on first glance that the divergence can be defined even without an orientation on the manifold.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you, that is what I will do. What would be an alternate definition of the divergence that is more apparent?

Comment: trace of the covariant derivative, or just good old local coordinates.

Comment: @CBBAM See [this recent answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4809538/788724)

Comment: @Didier Thank you, that was very helpful.